# html email template background image is not working

Tags: html, css

Here my email template : http://jsfiddle.net/p5K6N/

I tired few things, I took 2 `div`s, one `div` for image and 2nd for texts , and make `position : absolute`

`position : absolute` **<= is not working**

Another thing I tried was **background url of image** , but still it is not working for me :( - i found on internet it is not working, but what's the alternate solution here?

```
<p style="text-align: center; font-size: 18px; font-family: 'Segoe UI';">Pursue Your Brand</p>

<div style=" background-image:url('http://beautifullinux.com/web/wallpaper/SolarisExpressBuild69/images/di-scurve-gray.png'); background-size:100%; width: 100%; height:100%; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">
    some text will be disply here
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Emails are an absolutely awful thing to do because of the fact that there are many different mail clients(gmail, outlook, etc...) and they all run differently. I know from recent experience that outlook does not support background-image or the position styling at all. There is also a few clients that will rip any divs you have out for some reason! In short there is no solution that will run on all email clients because emails are the devil! I found this website helpful for testing my emails though. http://putsmail.com/

http://backgrounds.cm/ this could work for some situations though

Answer (score 1):

Please see http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/ Not every Mailclient supports Background pictures!

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style=" background-image:url...>
```

1. You have a space before `[space]background-image:url...` Take the space away.
2. Use `background` instead of `background-image` if you are going to give extra values such as `height`, `width`, etc.